# Header row is not repeated on the following pages automatically if filling the table with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a Word template, I have a table template consisting only of a header row, with "Allow row to break across pages" unset and "Repeat as header row at top of each page" set:

[image: table]
[image: row settings]

In a VBA script (from Excel via `Word.Application` if that matters), I add many data rows like the following, so that the table becomes larger than a page:

```
Dim table as Word.table
Set table = <get the table>
Dim data()
data = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

Dim r As Word.row, i, j As Long
For j = 1 to 100
    Set r = table.Rows.Add()
    For i = 0 To UBound(data)
        r.Cells.Item(i + 1).Range.Text = data(i)
    Next
Next
```

The data rows appear fine but the header row is not repeated on the following pages despite the setting.

---

The solutions found on the Net say the following:

- [Word 2013 & 2016 – Table ‘repeat header row’ not working – IT Support Guides](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/office-2013/word-2013-table-repeat-header-row-not-working/): Select the table (or place the cursor into any cell *on the first page of the table* <sub>(This is my own finding)</sub>), then on `Table Tools->Layout` ribbon pane, deselect and reselect `Repeat Header Rows`.

  This works, but I need to do this programmatically.
- [How to enable 'Repeat Header Rows' in a Word Table from VBA?](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20946654/How-to-enable-'Repeat-Header-Rows'-in-a-Word-Table-from-VBA.html):

  ```
  wd.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Select
  wd.Selection.Rows.HeadingFormat = True
  ```

  This has no effect.

Comment: Which version of Word is this? The screen shot of the dialog box looks really old... Is this Mac?

Comment: @CindyMeister Word 2007 in Win7. In any case, all the more recent versions show the same behavior.

Comment: Try:  
wd.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True

Comment: @Johan No effect if that's used by itself rather than how I wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug, most probably. I've seen it from Word 2007 all the way to 2016.

This is a workaround that I've found:

```
'Headings do not start replicating themselves on further pages automatically
'even though they should.
'Have to force their reformat manually.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
table.Rows(1).HeadingFormat = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
table.Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
```

**All the operations are required, as is the order.** Otherwise, there's no effect.

Comment: Huh. I've never had problems with setting table Header, before, but I confirm the problem and your workaround. Thank you!